# Logging from python in cloudbuild doesn't work

Tags: python, google-cloud-build

I'm running a cloudbuild with one of the steps:

```
- name: "gcr.io/something"
id: DO-STUFF
entrypoint: python
args: ['some_script.py']
waitFor:
  - WHATEVER
```

Inside my `some_script.py` I have some log statements:

```
...
LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)
...
LOGGER.info('Did work.')
...
```

Running the cloudbuild runs the script successfully, but I see no logs in the cloudbuild logs. How can I get them to be added there?

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure your logger to print the logs in the stdout stream. Update your code like this:

```
...
LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)
...
import sys
out_hdlr = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
# Format the output as you want. Let only the message if you don't care about other fields
out_hdlr.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(message)s'))
out_hdlr.setLevel(logging.INFO)
LOGGER.addHandler(out_hdlr)
...
LOGGER.info('Did work.')
...
```

**UPDATE**

Here my exact test process

Script to execute `script_log.py`

```
import logging
import sys
print("line0")
log = logging.getLogger()
out_hdlr = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
out_hdlr.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(message)s'))
out_hdlr.setLevel(logging.INFO)
log.addHandler(out_hdlr)
log.setLevel(logging.INFO)

log.info("THIS IS AN ERROR")
```

Cloud Build file definition (`cloudbuild.yaml` file)

```
steps:
        - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
          entrypoint: "bash"
          args:
                  - "-c"
                  - |
                          python3 script_log.py
```

Here the result of the command `gcloud builds submit`

```
Operation completed over 1 objects/415.0 B.
BUILD
Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
line0
THIS IS AN ERROR
PUSH
DONE
```

And the log in the stackdriver logging

[image]

The only difference is that I don't have the `__name__` in the getLogger()

Comment: Switching from logging to print statements makes them visible in the cloudbuild logs. I do have the `__main__` section but I don't think that can cause logging not to work. I want to try that though.